# Kubernates persistence disk (Mongodb) wipe off when node pool upgrade

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a question about Kubernetes. When auto upgrade node, related databases are wiped off.What is the reason for that ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your reclaim policy. The reclaim policy for a PersistentVolume tells the cluster what to do with the volume after it has been released of its claim. When node upgrade happens it may release the volume.

You should set Retail reclaim policy in your case if you want to keep the data.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: block-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
```

Comment: Can you tell me where want to add this change.Is it mongo.yml or deployment.yml
This is my app-mongo.yml
[https://docs.google.com/document/d/1EVJ70hyMqnxpzWTHV2-HTPaKeIHdYR0AHBJ8Bapz5b4/edit?usp=sharing]

Comment: @YMA in volumeClaimTemplates.spec

Comment: Is it possible to re-attach the Retained volumes?

Answer (score 1):

Explanation about the issue's likely cause on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54218348/10891425) seems to be right. By default, the Reclaim Policy is set to *Delete*.

I was unable to change the setting at *volumeClaimTemplates.spec* level (I get this error: `unknown field "persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PersistentVolumeClaimSpec`).

What I found to be allowed is to change the Reclaim Policy on an [existing PV](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/change-pv-reclaim-policy/#changing-the-reclaim-policy-of-a-persistentvolume) by locating it and running:

`kubectl patch pv <pv-name> -p '{"spec":{"persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy":"Retain"}}'`

You could also create a new *StorageClass* with the desired [reclaim policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#the-storageclass-resource) for new PVs or PVCs.